# Right button in the UI navigation controller is not getting displayed in Monotouch

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am tryin to add a custom button in the UI navigation controller toll bar i dis this as follows

1. created a class derived from UInavigation controller

2 .Overloaded the viewdidload as follows

{

logoutbutton = new UIbarbutton{..}

navigationitem.RightBArbutton = logoutbutton
}

Please help me in resolving the issue

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work

```
_addButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add);
_rootVC.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = _addButton;
```